# Error Controller Not Found In Back-Office - Custom Controller

Tags: php, controller, content-management-system, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I developped new module in prestashop 1.6 in my local server, everything was nice.But when i installed it into my hosting server i get controller not found error when i click into module tab.

I can enter to configure the module via prestashop configurer link, i get the configuration page and it works nice.

I thought it comes from capitals letters, i check if all files names are identicals but i found everything are in good format.

Really, a strong problem this one, i must to deliver the product today to the client i don't know what to do.

Please, i need your help, everything can help, an idea , a link to tutorial, ....

Comment: Let me guess... You're using Windows? Hosting enviroments use Linux, which means that file names are case sensitive, unlike in Windows

Comment: Yes i am using windows and Hosting enviroments use Linux, but i use the same name (identical)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My module name was yeStock, i changed it to yestock by changing S to s, and it works nice.
My hosting server use linux system so it is sensitive case, i made a stupid mistake.as far as i know in prestashop, we should putting lowercase letters especially for module class name.